# Change Amazon ComboBox via VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I try to write a VBA macro which automatize my work in Internet Explorer. My goal is to catch already opened Amazon webpage, and make a value of dropdown menu for "Books".
Currently I am able to catch running Amazon website, but I do not know how to change a value of dropdown menu.

```
Sub amazonCheck()

Dim element As Object
Dim i As Integer


'get opened Amazon session
Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set shellWins = New ShellWindows
i = shellWins.Count

On Error Resume Next
For i = 0 To i
    If shellWins.Item(i).Parent = "Internet Explorer" Then
        Debug.Print shellWins.Item(i).Document.URL
        shellWins.Item(i).Visible = True

        If shellWins.Item(i).Document.URL = "http://www.amazon.com/" Then
            Set IE = shellWins.Item(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0


'try to get dropdown box/ I think it is working fine,
Set element = IE.Document.getElementByID("searchDropdownBox").Item(0)

'try to change a value of dropdown box/ It does nothing
element.Value = "Books"
End Sub
```

Here you can see an example of Amazon HTML code (I do not know HTML it is possible, that I'm searching in wrong part of code)

```
<select class="nav-search-dropdown searchSelect" data-nav-digest="zOQ511tmF9BlHuHLk7aFmmjL+iA" data-nav-selected="0" id="searchDropdownBox" name="url" tabindex="18" title="Search in">
<option selected="selected" value="search-alias=aps">All Departments</option>
<option value="search-alias=instant-video">Amazon Video</option>
<option value="search-alias=appliances">Appliances</option>
<option value="search-alias=mobile-apps">Apps &amp; Games</option>
<option value="search-alias=arts-crafts">Arts, Crafts &amp; Sewing</option>
<option value="search-alias=automotive">Automotive</option>
<option value="search-alias=baby-products">Baby</option>
<option value="search-alias=beauty">Beauty</option>
<option value="search-alias=stripbooks">Books</option>
<option value="search-alias=popular">CDs &amp; Vinyl</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

I do not know HTML, it migh be very easy or impossible to do.
Do you have any tips?

Comment: Perhaps `element.Value = "search-alias=stripbooks"`

Comment: Hi,
no unfortunatelly it also does nothing. (also no error is returned)

Comment: ok, now is saw - IT is working, it just was not refreshed in the screen. Sorry for that, and thanks a lot Jeeped!

Comment: I was just composing a reply to state the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the value of the **<select>** element is a small matter. Whether it is critically important to also update the screen to reflect the change is another matter.

```
'try to get dropdown box/ I think it is working fine,
Set element = IE.Document.getElementByID("searchDropdownBox")   '.Item(0) <~~ do not need this on the end

'try to change a value of dropdown box/ It does nothing
element.selectedIndex = 4  'set to Arts, Crafts and Sewing
element.Value = "search-alias=stripbooks"   'set to Books
```

If you step through your code with F8 you can first set the **searchDropdownBox** select element to *Arts, Crafts and Sewing* and confirm this by returning to the visible IE window and clicking the select dropdown. Tap F8 once more and you can similarly confirm that the selection is set to *Books*.